# Implementing a naming standard for keys, indexes, constraints

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a database with a lot of tables, and I want to rename the primary/foreign keys, indexes and default constraints according to the following rules :

- Primary keys : `PK_<table name>`
- Foreign keys : `FK_<table_name>_<column name1>_column name2>...`
- Indexes      : `IX_<table_name>_<column name1>_column name2>...`
- Default Constraints  : `DF_<table_name>_<column name>`
- Check Constraints  : `CK_<table_name>_<column name>`

Someone has already done a similar SQL script ?

Comment: Can you specify more rules, e.g. if your index is filtered or has INCLUDE columns, do you want to specify those as well, or just key columns? What about check constraints and unique constraints?

Comment: Can't say I have, but I never use the GUI to create stuff, and I always give my stuff names in the script. You could probaly do the above, but I think it would be easier to script out the db and edit that to get what you want, than figure out the above.

Comment: Another thought is how to deal with objects that have underscores in their name. Can be quite confusing to read the object name of a foreign key for the case where `Document_Folder` has a column named `Folder_Name` referenced by `Document`s `Folder_Name` column. `FK_Document_Folder_Name_Document_Folder_Folder_Name`? I'm not sure that's any more useful than the system-generated name `FK__Document__Docum__1DE57479`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand : I don't want the referenced columun, with your example the foreign key name should be `FK_Document_Folder_name` and it's somewhat better than `FK__Document__Docum__1DE57479`

Comment: Can you clarify your question then? It currently says `FK_<table_name>_<column name1>_column name2>...`

Comment: You've also left out unique constraints - do you want those handled along with indexes, or separately? Unique constraint is implemented as a unique index, but you can still indicate it differently if the difference in your model is intentional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To rename Primary Keys to simply `PK_TableName`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Rename_PrimaryKeys
    @PrintOnly BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'EXEC sp_rename ''' 
        + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''') + ''', ''PK_' 
        + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), '''', '') + ''', ''OBJECT'';'
    FROM sys.key_constraints
    WHERE type = 'PK'
    AND name <> 'PK_' + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), '''', '')
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(parent_object_id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0;

    PRINT @sql;

    IF @PrintOnly = 0 AND @sql > N''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
END
GO
```

To rename FKs with the scheme `FK_TableName_col_col_ReferencedName_col_col`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Rename_ForeignKeys_WithColumns
    @PrintOnly BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
    + 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''')
        + ''', ''FK_' + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id), '''', '') 
    + '_' + STUFF((SELECT '_' + REPLACE(c.name, '''', '')
        FROM sys.columns AS c 
            INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc 
            ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
            AND fkc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
        WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
        ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id 
        FOR XML PATH(''), 
        TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') 
    + '_' + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id), '''', '')
    + '_' + STUFF((SELECT '_' + REPLACE(c.name, '''', '')
        FROM sys.columns AS c 
            INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc 
            ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c.column_id
            AND fkc.referenced_object_id = c.[object_id]
        WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
        ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id 
        FOR XML PATH(''), 
        TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')  
        + ''', ''OBJECT'';'
    FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(parent_object_id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0;

    PRINT @sql;

    IF @PrintOnly = 0 AND @sql > N''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
END
GO
```

For foreign keys if you just want `FK_TableName_ReferencedName` then it's a lot simpler:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Rename_ForeignKeys
    @PrintOnly BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'EXEC sp_rename ''' 
        + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''') + ''', ''FK_' 
        + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), '''', '') 
        + '_' + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id), '''', '')
        + ''', ''OBJECT'';'
    FROM sys.foreign_keys
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(parent_object_id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0;

    PRINT @sql;

    IF @PrintOnly = 0 AND @sql > N''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
END
GO
```

For indexes, this will rename any indexes `IX_TableName_Col1_Col2...`. It will ignore primary keys (since they are dealt with separately above), will add `UQ_` to unique indexes/constraints (so `IX_UQ_TableName_Col1_Col2...`, will treat unique constraints and unique indexes the same, and will ignore included columns. (Note that ignoring included columns could produce a naming conflict if you have redundant indexes that only differ by included columns.)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Rename_Indexes
    @PrintOnly BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
        + 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + REPLACE(i.name, '''', '''''')
        + ''', ''IX_' + CASE is_unique_constraint WHEN 1 THEN 'UQ_' ELSE '' END
        + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id]), '''', '') 
        + '_' + STUFF((SELECT '_' + REPLACE(c.name, '''', '')
            FROM sys.columns AS c 
                INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
                ON ic.column_id = c.column_id
                AND ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
            WHERE ic.[object_id] = i.[object_id] 
            AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
            AND is_included_column = 0
            ORDER BY ic.index_column_id 
            FOR XML PATH(''), 
            TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')  
        +''', ''OBJECT'';'
    FROM sys.indexes AS i
    WHERE index_id > 0 
    AND is_primary_key = 0 -- dealt with separately
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(i.[object_id], 'IsMsShipped') = 0;

    PRINT @sql;

    IF @PrintOnly = 0 AND @sql > N''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
END
GO
```

For default constraints:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Rename_DefaultConstraints
    @PrintOnly BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
        + 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + REPLACE(dc.name, '''', '''''') 
        + ''', ''DF_' + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(dc.parent_object_id), '''','') 
        + '_' + REPLACE(c.name, '''', '') + ''', ''OBJECT'';'
    FROM sys.default_constraints AS dc
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON dc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
    AND dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(dc.parent_object_id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0;

    PRINT @sql;

    IF @PrintOnly = 0 AND @sql > N''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
END
GO
```

And finally check constraints:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Rename_CheckConstraints
    @PrintOnly BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
        + 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + REPLACE(cc.name, '''', '''''') 
        + ''', ''CK_' + REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(cc.parent_object_id), '''','') 
        + '_' + REPLACE(c.name, '''', '') + ''', ''OBJECT'';'
    FROM sys.check_constraints AS cc
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON cc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
    AND cc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(dc.parent_object_id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0;

    PRINT @sql;

    IF @PrintOnly = 0 AND @sql > N''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
END
GO
```

Note that `PRINT` won't necessarily reveal the entire statement, depending on your settings for results in text and the size of the statement. But it should be good enough to eyeball that the scripts are doing the right job. I set them all to `PrintOnly` by default.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I always learn something new with your answers.

Answer (score 2):

And to rename the foreign keys, you can use something like this (this is not yet doing *exactly* what you wanted - but close enough to get started on it):

```
DECLARE RenameFKCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR 
    SELECT
       'dbo.sp_rename @objName = ''' + fk.Name + ''', @NewName = ''FK_' + t.Name + '_' + ref.Name + ''', @objtype = ''OBJECT'''
    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables t ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables ref ON fk.referenced_object_id = ref.object_id
    WHERE
        fk.is_system_named = 1

DECLARE @RenameFKStmt NVARCHAR(500)

OPEN RenameFKCursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM RenameFKCursor INTO @RenameFKStmt

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        PRINT @RenameFKStmt
        EXEC(@RenameFKStmt)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM RenameFKCursor INTO @RenameFKStmt
END

CLOSE RenameFKCursor 
DEALLOCATE RenameFKCursor 
GO
```

Basically, you iterate over all foreign keys defined in your database, and you rename them to some name that you decide on how to construct in the `SELECT` that is the basis of this cursor.

Then you run the cursor over all results, and execute the `dbo.sp_rename` stored procedure to rename your FK constraint to whatever you want them to be.

Using Aaron's approach of just basically building up one single huge SQL statement, you could even get away without having to use a cursor.

This would be the very similar code to rename the "system-named" default constraints to your own naming convention - it uses the same approach as above, a `SELECT` against the system catalog views, and then a cursor to iterate over all entries and build up and execute a SQL rename statement:

```
DECLARE DFCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
FOR
    SELECT 
        dc.Name,
        t.Name,
        c.Name
    FROM 
        sys.default_constraints dc
    INNER JOIN  
        sys.tables t ON dc.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns c ON dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id AND dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE 
        is_system_named = 1

DECLARE @OldConstraintName sysname, @TableName sysname, @ColumnName sysname

OPEN DFCursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM DFCursor  INTO @OldConstraintName, @TableName, @ColumnName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Stmt NVARCHAR(999)

    SET @Stmt = 'dbo.sp_rename @objName = ''' + @OldConstraintName + ''', @NewName = ''DF_' + @TableName + '_' + @ColumnName + ''', @objtype = ''OBJECT'''

    PRINT @Stmt
    EXEC (@Stmt)

    FETCH NEXT FROM DFCursor INTO @OldConstraintName, @TableName, @ColumnName
END

CLOSE DFCursor 
DEALLOCATE DFCursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided solutions will break if DB has similar tables in different schemas. Here's  my  modification of [this solution](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2709/script-to-rename-constraints-and-indexes-to-conform-to-a-sql-server-naming-convention/), that i use.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo._ImplementNamingStandard
@SELECT_Only        BIT = 1,
@PrimaryKeys        BIT = 1,
@ForeignKeys        BIT = 1,
@Indexes            BIT = 1,
@UniqueConstraints  BIT = 1,
@DefaultConstraints BIT = 1,
@CheckConstraints   BIT = 1 

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @cr CHAR(2);
SELECT @sql = N'', @cr = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);


DECLARE @TableLimit TINYINT, @ColumnLimit TINYINT;
SELECT @TableLimit = 24, @ColumnLimit = 24;
```

Primary Keys:

```
IF @PrimaryKeys = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + @cr + N'/* ---- Primary Keys ---- */' + @cr;
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + N'EXEC sp_rename @objname = N'''
        + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.'
        + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''') + ''', @newname = N''PK_' 
        + LEFT(REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), '''', ''), @TableLimit) + ''';'
    FROM sys.key_constraints
    WHERE type = 'PK'
    AND is_ms_shipped = 0;
END
```

Foreign Keys:

```
IF @ForeignKeys = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + @cr + N'/* ---- Foreign Keys ---- */' + @cr;
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + N'EXEC sp_rename @objname = N''' 
        + SCHEMA_NAME(f.schema_id) + '.'
        + REPLACE(f.name, '''', '''''') + ''', @newname = N''FK_' 
        + LEFT(REPLACE(t.name, '''', ''), @TableLimit)
        + '_' + LEFT(REPLACE(t2.name, '''', ''), @TableLimit)           
        + '_' + LEFT(REPLACE(c.name, '''', ''), @ColumnLimit)
        + ''';'
    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys as f
        inner join  sys.foreign_key_columns as fk on f.object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
        inner join sys.tables as t on fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id         
        inner join sys.tables as t2 on fk.referenced_object_id = t2.object_id
        inner join sys.columns as c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and 
                                        fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id 


    WHERE f.is_ms_shipped = 0;
END
```

Unique constraints:

```
 IF (@UniqueConstraints = 1 OR @Indexes = 1)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + @cr + N'/* ---- Indexes / Unique Constraints ---- */' + @cr;
            SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + N'EXEC sp_rename @objname = N''' 
       + CASE is_unique_constraint WHEN 0 THEN
       QUOTENAME(REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id]), '''', '''''')) + '.' ELSE '' END
                + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(i.name, '''', '''''')) + ''', @newname = N'''
                + CASE is_unique_constraint WHEN 1 THEN 'UQ_' ELSE 'IX_'
                  + CASE is_unique WHEN 1 THEN 'U_'  ELSE '' END 
                END + CASE has_filter WHEN 1 THEN 'F_'  ELSE '' END
                + LEFT(REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id]), '''', ''), @TableLimit) 
                + '_' + STUFF((SELECT '_' + LEFT(REPLACE(c.name, '''', ''), @ColumnLimit)
                    FROM sys.columns AS c 
                        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
                        ON ic.column_id = c.column_id
                        AND ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
                    WHERE ic.[object_id] = i.[object_id] 
                    AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                    AND is_included_column = 0
                    ORDER BY ic.index_column_id FOR XML PATH(''), 
                    TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') +''';'
            FROM sys.indexes AS i
            WHERE index_id > 0 AND is_primary_key = 0 AND type IN (1,2)
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(i.[object_id], 'IsMsShipped') = 0;
        END
```

Default constraints:

```
IF @DefaultConstraints = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + @cr + N'/* ---- DefaultConstraints ---- */' + @cr;
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + N'EXEC sp_rename @objname = N''' 
        + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.'
        + REPLACE(dc.name, '''', '''''') + ''', @newname = N''DF_' 
        + LEFT(REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(dc.parent_object_id), '''',''), @TableLimit)
        + '_' + LEFT(REPLACE(c.name, '''', ''), @ColumnLimit) + ''';'
    FROM sys.default_constraints AS dc
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON dc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
    AND dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    AND dc.is_ms_shipped = 0;
END
```

Check Constraints:

```
IF @CheckConstraints = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + @cr + N'/* ---- CheckConstraints ---- */' + @cr;
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + N'EXEC sp_rename @objname = N'''
        + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' 
        + REPLACE(cc.name, '''', '''''') + ''', @newname = N''CK_' 
        + LEFT(REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(cc.parent_object_id), '''',''), @TableLimit)
        + '_' + LEFT(REPLACE(c.name, '''', ''), @ColumnLimit) + ''';'
    FROM sys.check_constraints AS cc
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON cc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
    AND cc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    AND cc.is_ms_shipped = 0;
END


SELECT @sql;


IF @SELECT_Only = 0 AND @sql > N''
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
```